# Regex which matches sequence of signs and number with space beetwen

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, removing-whitespace

I have a problem with my Pattern, which i want to find a word("abc"), word with number(`"abc1"`), space between(`"abc "`) and a separete number, which should give `"abc 1"`.

This is my pattern: `"(\\w* \\d*)[\\s]*"` , but it gives output with too many whitespace, which i dont want to.

So, when String to match is: `def 3 abc 2 ghi 2 xyz 1`, the output should be:

1. "def 3"
2. "abc 2"
3. "ghi 2"
4. "xyz 1"

   My output is looks the same, but after number gives additional whitespace. I'm grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Update your regex.

**(\w*\s*\d*)[\s]***

You might read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html to understand how regex works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
\\w+\\s?\\d*
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OPopzb/1)**